# How to list all programs installed that were compiled from source?

Tags: compiling

Programs installed from source code do not show up in package managers. Is there another location that records all programs which were installed via compiling?

Comment: No, since the actions involved in `make install ` don't involve keeping records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, installing something from source is just copying files, it's not recorded anywhere. However, by default programs installed from source are copied in `/usr/local/bin`, while programs installed from packages are copied in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, so `ls /usr/local/bin` can give you a rough idea of what you have installed from source *if* you didn't use `--prefix=/usr`.

If you did use `--prefix=/usr`, you can still get to see which files where installed from a package and which were not using `dpkg -S`: `dpkg -S FILE` will look to see if `FILE` was installed from a package. If it was, it will print the name of the package, otherwise it will print an error. So if you want to see which files in `/usr/bin` were *not* installed form a package, you can do

```
for i in /usr/bin; do dpkg -S "$i" || echo "$i" >> ~/notfrompackages.txt; done
```

and it will write in `notfrompackages.txt` a list of all files in `/usr/bin` which were *not* installed from a package.